# Python & Pandas: missing rows when combining csv's

Tags: python, pandas, csv

New to Python and Pandas, all insights appreciated on this.

I'm working on a script that takes two csvs and combines them. However, the final output fails to write some rows, or those rows get overwritten - it's unclear to me what's happening.

The first csv, `posts.csv` is structured like this, with 21 rows (with a header row):

```
user_id,    text
6354,   text1
5457,   text2
5109,   text3
```

The second csv, `replies.csv` is similarly structured, with 38 rows (including header). The `user_id` field in the first and second csv's refers to the same users:

```
user_id,    text
5457,   texta
5109,   textb
5350,   textc
```

Here's my code for combining the two csv's:

```
df = pd.concat(
    map(pd.read_csv, ['posts.csv', 'replies.csv']), ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv("Control2.csv", index=False)
```

My output file, `Control2.csv`, should contain 58 rows (57 rows + 1 header row). However, only 43 rows are written. It appears there are missing rows from both csv's. Any idea what may be happening here? All assistance appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import multiple csv files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe)

Comment: Many thanks for this link. However, the same issue occurred with the script on that page - exact same rows are missing.

Comment: This question would be easier to answer if you would provide plain text for both csvs.

Comment: Edits made for plain text - thanks.

Comment: This is a guess only, but is your user_id column being read in as the index? because if so, and if you have matching indexes in both files that could maybe be the issue?

Comment: I can't reproduce. Both provided csvs read in correctly and the appended results produce the expected output file in pandas 1.3.1.

Comment: @DanielHutchinson I dont think pandas is a must in this case.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

See below (no external lib is needed)
The idea is to read the first file headers + data. For the other files we will read the data only.

```
file_names = ['1.csv', '2.csv']
with open('result.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    for idx, file_name in enumerate(file_names):
        with open(file_name) as infile:
            if idx == 0:
                outfile.write(infile.read())
            else:
                lines = infile.readlines()[1:]
                outfile.writelines(lines)
```